# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file

Tags: oracle

I was getting the below given error, When I run the application:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
.
.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file : '/fld1/fld2/mytemp_tablespace.dbf'
```

I tried to find out this files and came to know that there is no folders. I have , 
then created the respective folders and a new empty `mytemptemp_tablespace.dbf` file. But still the same error is getting over there.

Any idea why this error is happening?If it is an SQL exception it could have happened at the right beginning itself.
What I have done is, I have created a new schema and exported the db from the old to this new one.

Also how can I see or get the `DBWR trace file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the result of a restored database and during the restore rman was not able to create the tempfiles because of a missing directory.
Solution is quite simple, once the directories are created, just add one or more tempfiles:

```
alter tablespace mytemp_tablespace add tempfile '/fld1/fld2/mytemp_tablespace01.dbf';
```

when the temp tablespace has it's storage, your actions can succeed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I was still facing the issue, even I created the empty table space. And finally, it was a permission issue. Changed the permission to 777 and got it worked now. May help somebody.